# Make Notifyicon Appear on the MDIParent

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Application I had a Main Menu Which is the MDIParent It has a menustrip in top to navigate to different forms and a panel in the bottom which contains a labelcontrol used to dispaly error messages and status.
My requirement is when there is any pending jobs left for the user ( it will be optained by a select query) I want to show a pop up like "You have pending jobs ", I wish to use a notify icon for that .

But my problem is the notify icon is always apperaing in the start bar of my Pc not on my application mdiparent

Can anyone suggest any remedy for that or any better ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wish to use a notify icon for that

Use a [`ToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) class:

```
var toolTip = new ToolTip
{
    IsBalloon = true,
    ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info,
    ToolTipTitle = "Pending jobs"
};

// 'this' means form
toolTip.Show("You have pending jobs", this, yourMdiParent.Location);
```